# Get 'Failed prop type: Invalid prop `appBar` supplied to `Layout`' warning when using Layout from example demo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

Get warning 'Failed prop type: Invalid prop `appBar` supplied to `Layout`' when using Layout from example demo.

I am learning from react-admin's demo project code from https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/demo. I copy the Layout.js and AppBar.js to my own project, and did some modification to AppBar.js. They works fine. However, I see a warning "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `appBar` supplied to `Layout`."

```
// I remove Logo from AppBar
import { AppBar, UserMenu, MenuItemLink, translate } from 'react-admin';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// const styles = {...}    

// const CustomUserMenu = ...

const CustomAppBar = ({ classes, ...props }) => (
    <AppBar {...props} userMenu={<CustomUserMenu />}>
        <Typography
            variant="inherit"
            color="inherit"
            className={classes.title}
            id="react-admin-title"
        />
        <span className={classes.spacer} />
    </AppBar>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomAppBar);
```

I expect there is no warning message.

Comment: This appears to be either a doc bug or something related. Probably more appropriate for their GitHub here: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues